# Using protocol register of Http client method in scala

Tags: scala, ssl, https, httpclient

I want to use custom ssl so I added a .jar (`commons-httpclient-contrib.jar`) with the following files:

> META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.class
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.EasyX509TrustManager.class
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.StrictSSLProtocolSocketFactory.class
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.utils.HttpMethodCloner.class

```
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", new MySSLSocketFactory(), 443));
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("https://www.whatever.com/");
try {
  httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
  System.out.println(httpget.getStatusLine());
} finally {
  httpget.releaseConnection();
}
```

I am trying to convert above code to scala. But I haven't been successful, and have compilation errors.

Comment: We can't help you fix compilation errors if we don't see the code you ended up writing